# exact string match for selenium dropdown

Tags: python, string, selenium, tkinter, match

I  am trying to exactly match a string with a dropdown menu on a website

```
    # Check if a specific position is chosen or if it is left default / empty
    if str_sv_pos == "position" or str_sv_pos == "":
        pass
    else:
        try:
            # press on the drop down container
            pos_dropdown_menu = init_webdriver.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div"
            )
            pos_dropdown_menu.click()
            
            # define variable "my_pos_string" taken out of a input field in my GUI
            my_pos_string = str(str_sv_pos)

            # choose the correct position from the container list
            find_pos = init_webdriver.wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (
                        By.XPATH,
                        (
                            "//li[@class='with-icon' and contains(text(),'"
                            + my_pos_string
                            + "')]"
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
            find_pos.click()
        except:
            pass
```

This works for most of the positions.

But the issue is, that inside the container there is a "LW" and a "LWB" included. And "LWB" comes before "LW" and so it chooses "LWB".

So I want to exactly match my input in the GUI to avoid that.

How can  I do that in my example?

Comment: Found the solution here in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713366/12470444

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `contains()` XPath function, look into using the `text()` XPath function.

[This answer to a very similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7767663/9902610) should tell you all you need to know to solve your problem.